# Revit Ironpython Shell - Parsing a list of filenames with a number after a backslash in the path

Tags: path, numbers, ironpython, revit, slash

I want to read in a list of files (inc path) from either a spreadsheet or a text file for some downstream processing. The list has been generated as a log from another process and the path includes a 2 digit year folder followed by a project number folder as follows:

`\\servername\projects\19\1901001\project files\filetobeprocessed.abc`

The problem is as soon as the above string is read in, it is interpreted as

`\\servername\\projects\x019\x01901001\\project files\x0ciletobeprocessed.abc`

Which then means that I cannot use the path to access the file.

Assigning the path string to a variable, I have tried:

`thePath = repr(pathreadfromfile)`

After assigning the path string I have tried fixing the string using

`thePath.replace('\x0','\\')`

`thePath.replace('\\x0','\\')`

`thePath.replace(r'\x0','\\')`

Nothing seems to fix the path so that it can be used to open the file.
I can't find anything in either python or Ironpython that suggests a fix for this programatically. I know that you can fix this is the path is known within the code by using r'' to use raw text to create the path.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously, the backslash `\` is interpreted as an escape character.

For a really simple solution, hopefully the simplest, I would suggest using forward slash `/` for all your path separators instead of backslash.

If you really need the backslash somewhere further down the road, you can replace them back again.

Comment: Legend... Thanks Jeremy... that works a treat \o/... Rather than continue to fight with the paths within revit and replace the slashes programatically I decided to replace them in the excel list before reading them in to the python shell...

Comment: Great! Glad that it helped! Please upvote my answer, then, so that others can enjoy it as well. Thank you!